# Google Apps Script - While loop

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would appreciate any inputs on this Google Apps Script code!

I am trying to implement a do-while loop to copy the formula from cell B2 to C2 and follow that sequence from B3 to c3, B4 to c4, and so on.

The condition that I want to give to the do while loop is that as long as the active cell is > 0, the loop runs. If I remove the loop from the script and I run the code manually, it will work but with the code it gets stuck.

**Copy of challenge and script in tab 1 and 2 here:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3ZZBar2BExaFhOMzpjpAbDFMTDmupuX4x0irwv3ixM/copy

**Images below:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add code as text not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do what you are asking for:

```
function fillFormulaDown() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let currentCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  while (currentCell.getValue()) {
    let formula = currentCell.getFormulaR1C1();
    if (formula) {
      currentCell.offset(0, 1).setFormulaR1C1(formula);
    }
    currentCell = currentCell.offset(1, 0);
  }
}
```

...but that is an inefficient way of copying a larger number of formulas, because each cell is read and written separately. You can make the code run tens of times faster with something like this:

```
function betterFillFormulaDown() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const currentCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  const numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - currentCell.getRow() + 1;
  const currentColumn = currentCell.offset(0, 0, numRows, 1);
  const values = currentColumn.getValues().flat();
  const formulas = currentColumn.getFormulas().flat();
  const numFormulasToCopy = values.findIndex((value, index) => !value || !formulas[index]);
  if (!numFormulasToCopy) {
    return;
  }
  if (numFormulasToCopy === -1) {
    numFormulasToCopy = numRows;
  }
  const rangeToCopy = currentCell.offset(0, 0, numFormulasToCopy, 1);
  rangeToCopy.offset(0, 1).setFormulasR1C1(rangeToCopy.getFormulasR1C1());
}
```

The better function runs faster, because it gets and sets a larger number of cells in one go. Operating on one cell with `.setFormula()` costs about the same as operating on one thousand cells with `.setFormulas()`.

The copying will stop at the first cell that is blank, zero or does not contain a formula.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!!! It seems I was very far from the right script. I will apply the one you suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi! going back to the example above. I have been trying to add the Filteredbyuser to the script below but is not working for me.                                                                                                  function fillFormulaDown() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let currentCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  while (currentCell.getValue()) {
    let formula = currentCell.getFormulaR1C1();
    if (formula) {
      currentCell.offset(0, 1).setFormulaR1C1(formula);
    }
    currentCell = currentCell.offset(1, 0);
  }
}

Comment: The is a different question. Please post a new question, and describe the _problem_ rather than describing your _attempted solution_.  See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)